# Specifying default value(s) for rows that don't match on an INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an inner join, but I want it to select a default row if it does not find any match on the field [prices.Item], say a row in [Prices] with 'Unassigned' as the [Item] and a [Price] equal to 5. My code for the join is as follows:

```sql
SELECT 
    Orders.Item, 
    Orders.Quantity, 
    Prices.Price,
    Orders.Quantity * Prices.Price AS Cost
FROM
    Orders
    INNER JOIN
    Prices
        ON Orders.Item = Prices.Item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the results you desire we need to combine the results from two queries: one for items with prices that actually exist in the [Prices] table, and another for the items that don't have a "real" price. This is done using a UNION query.

For [Orders]...

```
Item     Quantity
-------  --------
Edam            1
Gouda           2
Brie            3
Cheddar         4
Havarti         5
```

...and [Prices]...

```
Item        Price
----------  -----
Edam           10
Gouda          11
Brie           12
Havarti        13
unassigned      5
```

...the query...

```sql
    SELECT 
        Orders.Item, 
        Orders.Quantity, 
        Prices.Price
    FROM 
        Orders 
        INNER JOIN 
        Prices 
            ON Orders.Item = Prices.Item
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Orders.Item,
        Orders.Quantity,
        DLookup("Price","Prices","Item='unassigned'") AS Price
    FROM
        Orders
        LEFT JOIN
        Prices
            ON Orders.Item = Prices.Item
    WHERE Prices.Item IS NULL
```

...returns

```
Item     Quantity  Price
-------  --------  -----
Edam            1  10   
Gouda           2  11   
Brie            3  12   
Havarti         5  13   
Cheddar         4  5
```

We can either save that query in Access (to use with other queries), or we can just put a "wrapper" around it to do the calculation

```sql
SELECT
    Item,
    Quantity,
    Price,
    Quantity * Price AS Cost
FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                Orders.Item, 
                Orders.Quantity, 
                Prices.Price
            FROM 
                Orders 
                INNER JOIN 
                Prices 
                    ON Orders.Item = Prices.Item
        UNION ALL
            SELECT
                Orders.Item,
                Orders.Quantity,
                DLookup("Price","Prices","Item='unassigned'") AS Price
            FROM
                Orders
                LEFT JOIN
                Prices
                    ON Orders.Item = Prices.Item
            WHERE Prices.Item IS NULL
    )
```

...which gives us

```
Item     Quantity  Price  Cost
-------  --------  -----  ----
Edam            1  10       10
Gouda           2  11       22
Brie            3  12       36
Havarti         5  13       65
Cheddar         4  5        20
```

Comment: I like the fact that you choose cheese as the item in the table it was a nice touch. Thanks for the information this really helped and was well structured.